# Zend application taking too long to load

Tags: php, zend-framework, server, response-time

I have a Zend application at one folder (**domain.com/portal**) and installed another at **domain.com/site**. Both works fine, except that the app at /portal loads really fast while the one at /site takes about 15s to load! Using Google PageSpeed I discovered that the main problem resides on the server time response.

Since I'm a newbie to Zend, is there any config to work around this problem?

ADDITIONAL INFO: The app uses MySQL database. Like I said, it uses Zend framework, so the site structure is the default. Although both sites loads lots os images, Pingdom (tools.pingdom.com) shows that most of the delay resides on the response from server (dreamhost).

Sites URL: camaraempauta.com.br/portal & camaraempauta.com.br/site

Thanks!

Comment: do you think we've enough information to help you ?

Comment: Sorry, like I said, I'm new to Zend. What kinda info do you need?

Comment: What's the code on **"the app at /portal"** ?

Comment: Or do you use a database?

Comment: I have provided additional informations to the question.

Comment: Install zdt and profile. Will give you extendet answer tonight.

Comment: Sure is a lot of stuff on that portal page. Does it all come from local db calls? Or are there some remote API calls (to things like RSS feeds, for example) that are not cached on your side?

Comment: Try to launch both sites on local computer and see if there will be significant difference in response. If it is then one has a problem. Intall xdebug and firephp and start debugging.